# CiviCRM Membership form with login

Tags: users, civicrm

I would like to sell subscriptions on a site and have the person logged in automatically.

I have setup the contribution page and it works fine. The person at the end of the process doesn't get a drupal account or become logged in. We created a custom module to create the person's account at the end of the process. We haven't found a way to log them in though.

Ideally the person can register/pay/be logged in as one step. We are afraid that if we get them to register a drupal account, confirm the account and then pay the membership we will lose a lot of people as it is 'too complicated'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programatically user from code, you need to replicate what [`user_login_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_submit/7) and [`user_login_finalize`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_finalize/7) are doing:

```
function user_login_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $user = user_load($form_state['uid']);
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'user/' . $user->uid;

  user_login_finalize($form_state);
}

function user_login_finalize(&$edit = array()) {
  global $user;
  watchdog('user', 'Session opened for %name.', array('%name' => $user->name));
  // Update the user table timestamp noting user has logged in.
  // This is also used to invalidate one-time login links.
  $user->login = REQUEST_TIME;
  db_update('users')->fields(array('login' => $user->login))->condition('uid', $user->uid)->execute();

  // Regenerate the session ID to prevent against session fixation attacks.
  // This is called before hook_user in case one of those functions fails
  // or incorrectly does a redirect which would leave the old session in place.
  drupal_session_regenerate();

  user_module_invoke('login', $edit, $user);
}
```

Just replace `$form_state['uid']` with UID you generated in earlier step, and maybe use other way to redirect.

Comment: I have the login working now. Still would expect it to work an easier way. Just $account = user_save(null, $newUser);      _user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $account);
          $user = user_load($account->uid);
          user_login_finalize($edit);

Comment: Programmatic solution is what I did. I dug into logintoboggan to find an implementation. So I used this answer, although it was more background than direct solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the code you ended up with if you have it available to add to the answer. Note that you can also allow Drupal user creation directly in a CiviCRM profile that you include in a contribution page through the admin interface, but I'm not sure if that logs them in automatically. It probably depends on your Drupal user settings.